# Entity Framework Performance - Each relational property call slow

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a large database that has one primary table with a few hundred thousand records, and then 30-40 different relational tables that join from it for additional data.

I created an EF connection to this database, and I was able to pull the data without an issue.

The goal for our project is to keep the 200K objects, in memory, in our own custom POCO classes that do not match the database structure we have. The idea here is that with the 200K items cached in memory, when someone goes to fetch 8000 of them, it should return extremely fast.

I was also able to achieve this using MemoryCache.

The problem is the original loading of the POCO clas objects. As I iterate through my List<> of records and populate my POCO objects, it seems to take more time than I had hoped. I believe that EF is making SQL calls for each record to get the relational data. So when i say:

```
foreach(var o in MyEntities.Stuff)
{
var x = new MyCustomClass();
x.Property1 = o.RelationalTableA.PropertyX;
x.Property2 = o.RelationalTableB.PropertyY;
x.Property3 = o.RelationalTableC.PropertyZ;
MyPocoList.Add(o);
}
```

This seems to take a few hundred milliseconds.

Well, for 100K items, that might be 300ms * 100,000 = 8 hours ...

Just setting the poco objects to hard coded values, for 100K items, takes a couple of minutes, which is a reasonable amount of time to load up a huge amount of records in memory.

Are there optimization approaches I can use with EF so that it isn't running join queries for each property I am setting?

Edited to add:

In my code, I am also creating different types of classes depending on value(s) in the returned record. For example:

```
IInterface x;
if(o.PropertyA == "A")
{
  x = new MyCustomClass1();
}
else if(o.PropertyA == "B")
{
  x = new MyCustomClass2();
}
```

.

Comment: What queries does SQL Server Profiler say are being executed against the server? Do you have adequate indexes and other DB optimizations?

Comment: try `foreach(var o in MyEntities.Stuff.ToList())`

Comment: Don't use EF if you want performance. Write a sproc and use a datareader. How big are your objects though? your hardcoded results seem slow. are you hitting the swap file or something?

Comment: you should be able to see the actual sql running if you use the sql profiler.

Comment: also I would add, I think your caching idea might be a bit off target. sql server is pretty dam good at returning results fast, and will do caching itself. so making your own 'in memory database' is of limited value. the real value of caching is removing load from the shared resouce of the db for known results sets

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: Ewan, the idea is that the data set is mostly static, but a good number of people may be calling it at the same time. The notion of the cached layer was to reduce the load on SQL for multiple people calling the same thing and not constantly doing the joins and such. I may be looking at it wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do two things (or use the alternative from @BG100):

1. Use [`.Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) to have the related entities loaded while loading the data
2. Use `.ToList()` (if you know the amount of data **in advance**) to have the data loaded *before* the enumerator for the `foreach` loop is executed. If you do not use `.ToList`, data is loaded while executing the query (that whould be the same as you would use a `SqlDataReader`)...

   ```
   foreach(var o in MyEntities.Stuff
           .Include(x => x.RelationalTableA)
           .Include(x => x.RelationalTableB)
           .Include(x => x.RelationalTableC)
           .ToList())
   {
       var x = new MyCustomClass();
       x.Property1 = o.RelationalTableA.PropertyX;
       x.Property2 = o.RelationalTableB.PropertyY;
       x.Property3 = o.RelationalTableC.PropertyZ;
       MyPocoList.Add(o);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I will give some of this a try and see how it performs.

Comment: This improved performance significantly, and in a sense it is the same as what I was prepared to do (forego EF and use a big stored procedure to bring all the data back flattened out ...). It now takes about 12 seconds to load 10,000 items. This can probably be tweaked further, but at least now it's reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably be better off doing the joins to the other tables manually:

```
var MyPocoList = 
    from x in MyEntities.Stuff
    join a in RelationalTableA on x.id == a.id
    join b in RelationalTableB on x.id == b.id
    select new MyCustomClass(X = a.PropertyX, Y = b.PropertyY);
```